# How to specify the correct xpath for parsing on this website?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I need to extract the company name, email, URL, address and phone number from [this table](https://privatschulen.de/aktuelles-mainmenu-48/vdp-schulsuche.html?page=1&&stxt=&sfld=alle%20Felder...&sfg1=Kindergarten%20/%20Kinderhort&sfg2=Bitte%20ausw%C3%A4hlen...&search=suchen&sorder=PLZ&bundesland=Bitte%20ausw%C3%A4hlen)...

The company names are quite straightforward, the correct xpath location for them is:

```
//*[@id="s5_component_wrap_inner"]/div[2]/div[2]/strong
```

However, the address and phone/fax information is merely seperated with `<br>`'s.

I have tried specifying :

```
//*[@id="s5_component_wrap_inner"]/div[2]/div[2]/text()
```

with no avail. I am using Octoparse 8.0

Here is the example of a table entry on the page:

```html
    <strong>Freie Grundschule 'Clara Schumann'</strong><br>Inselstraße 18, 04103 Leipzig<br />Tel.: 03 41 / 39 39 - 6 10, Fax: 03 41 / 39 39 - 6 11<br /><span id="cloak1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd">Diese E-Mail-Adresse ist vor Spambots geschützt! Zur Anzeige muss JavaScript eingeschaltet sein!</span><script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('cloak1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd').innerHTML = '';
        var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
        var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
        var addy1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd = 'gr&#117;ndsch&#117;l&#101;-lpz' + '&#64;';
        addy1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd = addy1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd + 'r&#97;hn-sch&#117;l&#101;n' + '&#46;' + 'd&#101;';
        var addy_text1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd = 'gr&#117;ndsch&#117;l&#101;-lpz' + '&#64;' + 'r&#97;hn-sch&#117;l&#101;n' + '&#46;' + 'd&#101;';document.getElementById('cloak1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd').innerHTML += '<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd + '\'>'+addy_text1ad4f2fdfed5ab713a02c518f5f184cd+'<\/a>';
      </script>, <a href="http://www.rahndittrich.de/gs-lpz/" target="_blank">www.rahndittrich.de/gs-lpz/</a><br /><span style="font-size:10px;line-height: normal; ">Begabtenförderung, Ganztagsschule<br /></span>
```

Comment: What did you try? post your code sample

Comment: Since I am using Octoparse to extract the information, I can not share any more code than I have.

Comment: It looks like the email is dynamic or obfuscate to prevent spam